# How could we assign environment variable to key "topicName" in service-bus-trigger/function.json

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

I have an azure function with type as serviceBusTrigger.
Right now the value of "topicName" is considered as a string.
I want to add the topicName as an enviroment variable (AZURE_FUNC_TOPIC_NAME) in app.settings.json.
would like to have value of this variable AZURE_FUNC_TOPIC_NAME to be assigned to the key topicName in below function.json
How could i achieve it?

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mySbMsg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_TOPIC",
      "connection": "",
      "subscriptionName": ""
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: Wrap it with `%`. like `"topicName": "%AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_TOPIC%",`. With this convention, the value of `AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_TOPIC` env variable will be used as topic name.

Answer (score 0):

**In `local.settings.json` file, define your variables like topic name in the `key-value` format and get that environment variable in your function code.**

To get an environment variable or an app setting value, use `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`, as shown below.

```cs
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
{
    return name + ": " + 
        System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
}
```

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#environment-variables

Comment: I want the value of env variable to be assigned to topic name.
its not about reading env variable in the code.